# Installing Tensorflow using python3.6 failing

Tags: python, tensorflow

This my environment at present

```
$ pip show tensorflow
Name: tensorflow
Version: 1.4.0
Summary: TensorFlow helps the tensors flow
Home-page: https://www.tensorflow.org/
Author: Google Inc.
Author-email: opensource@google.com
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: wheel, tensorflow-tensorboard, enum34, six, numpy, protobuf

$ pip show protobuf
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.5.0
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author: protobuf@googlegroups.com
Author-email: protobuf@googlegroups.com
License: 3-Clause BSD License
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires: six, setuptools

$pip show six
Name: six
Version: 1.11.0
Summary: Python 2 and 3 compatibility utilities
Home-page: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/six/
Author: Benjamin Peterson
Author-email: benjamin@python.org
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File
>   "/Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/**init**.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import *   File "/Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/**init**.py",
>   line 51, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "/Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 52, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 41, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "/Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 28, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "/Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 24, in swig_import_helper
>       _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)   File
>   "/Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 242, in
>   load_module
>       return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)   File "/Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 342, in
>   load_dynamic
>       return _load(spec) ImportError: dlopen(/Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so,
>   10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib   Referenced from:
>   /Users/joson/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
>     Reason: image not found

Comment: Really, I have no Idea, what you are trying to say, please mention your problem. is it that you have installed tensorflow and its not working on your system?

Comment: in my mac ,after >>> import tensorflow as tf, Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime

Comment: It looks like it's trying to find libcublas.8.0.dylib. Have you installed CUDA? What command are you using to install TensorFlow?

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_mac,the steps of Take the following steps to install TensorFlow with Virtualenv @MatthewScarpino

Comment: It's odd that the application is looking for CUDA if you're just installing regular TensorFlow. What happens if you just run `pip install tensorflow`?

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: protobuf>=3.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow)

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: enum34>=1.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.12.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow)

Comment: Requirement already satisfied: html5lib==0.9999999 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: bleach==1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from tensorflow-tensorboard<0.5.0,>=0.4.0rc1->tensorflow)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from protobuf>=3.3.0->tensorflow)@ MatthewScarpino

Comment: thinks very much ,I uninstall tensorflow，again install。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is that the **GPU** version of TensorFlow for Mac OS X was installed on a Mac without CUDA installed. Uninstalling and reinstalling the CPU version of TensorFlow  should fix the problem.

(Note that the GPU version of TensorFlow for Mac OS X is no longer officially supported.)